# Why does this LINQ expression break my loop & conversion logic?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities, foreach

#### Background

`ArticleService` is a class that provides methods for front-end layers to facilitate business with the back-end.

Two of its base responsibilities are to convert ViewModels (`ArticleViewModel`) to the appropriate Models (`Article`) when persisting data, and the reverse, convert Models to ViewModels when fetching data... so often that I created a private method building ViewModel objects:

```
private ArticleViewModel BuildViewModel(Article a)
{
    return new ArticleViewModel { Title = a.Title /* all properties */ }
}
```

Moving along, the `ArticleService` provides a method to fetch all articles from the data store, returning them as ViewModels: `public IEnumerable<ArticleViewModel> All()`

A calling class uses it like this: `var articleViewModels = _articleService.All();`

Simple, right?

#### Problem:

I originally wrote `All()` lazily with a classic `foreach` loop:

```
private IEnumerable<ArticleViewModel> All()
{
    var viewModels = new List<ArticleViewModel>();
    foreach (var article in _db.Articles)
        viewModels.Add(BuildViewModel(article));
    return viewModels;
}
```

It worked fine - `articleViewModels` was an instantiate list of all view models.

Next, I used ReSharper to convert this loop to a LINQ statement for performance and prettiness, and then combined the assignment statement with the return statement. Result:

```
private IEnumerable<ArticleViewModel> All()
{
    return _db.Articles.Select(article => BuildViewModel(article)).ToList();
}
```

I debugged the LINQ statement and the beast awakened:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ArticleViewModel
>   BuildViewModel(Article)' and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

#### Question - Why does this LINQ statement break my code?

*Note: Stepping back to an explicit declaration, assignment, return worked with the LINQ statement, so I'm almost certain it's something to do with the lambda logic.*

Comment: In all fairness, it's not the LINQ statement that broke your code: rather, it was ReSharper. If you add `.AsEnumerable()` between `_db.Articles` and `Select(...)`, everything will work fine again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Question - Why does this LINQ statement break my code?

Because LINQ to Entities is trying to translate `BuildViewModel` into SQL. It doesn't know how, so it dies miserably.

In your original version, you were streaming the entity from the database to your local box, and then doing the projection using `BuildViewModel` client-side. That's fine.

> so I'm almost certain it's something to do with the lambda logic.

Nope. It's because LINQ to Entities can't translate `BuildViewModel` into SQL. It doesn't matter if you use a lambda expression to express the projection or not.

You can rewrite the code like this:

```
return _db.Articles.
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(article => BuildViewModel(article)).ToList();
```

This causes `_db.Articles` to be treated as a plain old enumerable, and then does the projection client side. Now LINQ to Entities doesn't have to figure out what to do with `BuildViewModel`.

Comment: You can use .AsEnumerable here, rather than .ToList to avoid creating a list, populating it, and then subsequently discarding it.  There's also no real reason to call .ToList at the very end when, based on the OPs original code, an enumerable is clearly appropriate.

Comment: Thank you guys. `ToList()` was only used for debugging to compare apples to apples - obviously by the return object you could see the next step was remove any casting. What I am curious about then is efficiency/performance implications then with using AsEnumerable and doing the filtering/query projects in memory rather than from SQL. Any thoughts or info?

Comment: With `All()` this doesnt matter much due to its intentions, but let's say there is a condition on the select statement... what are the implications of a `.Where()` filter used before or after the `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: `Where` before `AsEnumerable` means that LINQ to Entities will try to translate the expression that you pass to the `Where` into SQL. `Where` after `AsEnumerable` means the `Where` will be executed in memory, client-side, as if it were just plain-old LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Jason explains the error, but doesn't [didn't] list the simple fix (if you still want to use LINQ).  Just add a call to .AsEnumerable() right after "_db.Articles".  This will force any future LINQ statements to be performed using LINQ to Objects (in memory) rather than trying to use the IQueryable to perform the statements against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Simply your function `BuildViewModel` is not traslable to raw `SQL`. That is.