# Creating empty IQueryable list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a list of empty IQueryable and change it to  ToPagedList, I tried the following code :-

```
IQueryable<VirtualMachine> vm2 = new IQueryable<VirtualMachine>();
vm2.ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
```

but it will raise the following exception:-

> Error 3   A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: in my case a requirement has come that I need to display records from other system , so I will be populating these values as viewData, and for my system record I will be creating empty Iquerable ,, so that I can reuse my current index view .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You *could* use something like this

```
 IQueryable<VirtualMachine> vm2 = new VirtualMachine[] {}.AsQueryable();
```

Do you actually want / need this though? [as on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the IQueryable interface is for use on data sources.

> Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source wherein the type of the data is known.

I would decide whether or not you actually need this before implementing it like this.

Comment: but this will create only one item inside the vm2 , while I need to create 10 empty items inside the vm2 ? is there a way to do so ?

Comment: So initialise 10 items in side the [collection initialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), again though, you probably really don't need this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an instance of an interface - there's no implementation

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an instance of an interface not an object. THis cannot be done.

Have a look at this SO question

[What instantiate-able types implementing IQueryable are available in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169915/what-instantiate-able-types-implementing-iqueryablet-are-available-in-net-4-0)

Paying special attention to this

> IQueryable objects are produced by Queryable Providers (ex. LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities/Entity Framework, etc). Virtually nothing you can instantiate with new in the basic .NET Framework implements IQueryable.