# OrderBy with Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, c#-7.0

I have the following:

```
Context context = new Context();

var persons = context.Persons.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name });   

var mapper = OrderMapper.For(persons).Add("name", x => x.Name);

var result = persons.OrderByWithMapper(mapper);
```

Where:

- persons is of type `IQueryable<anonymous>`
- mapper is of type `OrderMapper<anonymous>`
- the `OrderByWithMapper` is the following:

  ```
  public static IQueryable<T> OrderByWithMapper<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, OrderMapper<T> mapper) {
     // Method code
  }
  ```
- `OrderMapper` class is the following:

  ```
  public class OrderMapper {
    public static OrderMapper<T> For<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
      return new OrderMapper<T>();
    }
  }

  public class OrderMapper<T> {
  }
  ```

But I get an error when trying to create the Result:

```
 'List<<anonymous type: string Name>>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByWithMapper'
 and the best extension method overload 'OrderByWithMapper<<anonymous type: 
 string Name>>(IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name>>, OrderMapper<<anonymous type: string Name>>)' 
 requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name>>'
```

I am not sure what is wrong as the OrderBy method in EntityFramework works fine with anonymous, e.g.:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
```

What should I change in my OrderByWithMapper method to make it work with anonymous types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension method `OrderByWithMapper<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, OrderMapper<T> mapper)` expects an `IQueryable<T>` and an `OrderMapper<T>`

According to the error message, you are attempting to execute it on a `List<<anonymous type: string Name>>`

`List<T>` does not implement `IQueryable`

Either change your extension method to accept something else (such as `IEnumerable`) or change your input to provide an `IQueryable`.  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9170011/714151) for more info on the purpose of IQueryable.

Comment: Of course! I missed the ToList() on the end of my first query which turned it into a List<String> ...