# can not convert the class to System.Linq.IQueryable using .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here i have a class:

```
  public class AccessinfoDetails 
{
    public IEnumerable<TurbineDvce> Devices { get; set; }
    public TixiModem TixiModem { get; set; }
}
```

i have an interface which i defined like this:

```
  public IQueryable<AccessinfoDetails> Devices(string id);
```

for the implemntation of the interface:

```
    public IQueryable<AccessinfoDetails> Devices(string id){

      AccessinfoDetails result = new AccessinfoDetails()
        {
            Devices = distinct,
            TixiModem = tixiModem
        };

        return  result;}
```

but i get an error saying it can not convert AcessInfoDeatils to system.linq.iquerable
which is right,but how can i fix it and is it a right way to pass data to my API controller?

Comment: your interface defines, simply put, a _box of something_. you're returning _something_ - without the box..

Comment: @FranzGleichmann whats the fix?

Comment: Return an `IQueryable<AccessinfoDetails>` instead of an `AccessinfoDetails`, or change the return type to `AccessinfoDetails`. For more info, see: [What instantiate-able types implementing IQueryable<T> are available in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169915/what-instantiate-able-types-implementing-iqueryablet-are-available-in-net-4-0)

Comment: @ilmagnifico -- maybe you want to return an array with one element?

Comment: @Hogan no there are other queries there but the final query is the one i assigned to result,now i want to return it but i get that error

Comment: how to return this IQueryable<AccessinfoDetails>? i get an error

Comment: `return new List<AccessinfoDetails> { result }.AsQueryable();`

Comment: What do you mean by *"i get an error"*? Please post the code where you're trying to return an `IQueriable`, along with the error details

Comment: Isn't it pointless to return an `IQueryable<T>` when indeed all  you have to return is a `T`?

Comment: @bolkay im new in programming ,can you please tell me the right way of passing it to my controller?i dont want to do LINQ in my controller thats why i created an interface and them implemented it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, change your return line to look like this:

```
return  new [] {result}.AsQuerable();
```

or as Rufus L points out in the comments a typed version using list instead of array:

```
return new List<AccessinfoDetails> { result }.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: 'AccessinfoDetails' does not contain a definition for 'AsQuerable' and no accessible extension method 'AsQuerable' accepting a first argument of type 'AccessinfoDetails' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: did you add the using linq to the file @ilmagnifico

Comment: the second approach works,but it looks ugly i dont know whats the right way of doing this really

Comment: @ilmagnifico my way works too just make sure you have the `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the method is `IQueryable <AccessinfoDetails>`, it is a data collection, but the "result" in the method is a single data of type `AccessinfoDetails`.Not clear about your scenario.

If you don't want to change the return type of the method, you should change the method as shown:

```
 public IQueryable<AccessinfoDetails> Devices(string id)
    {
        List<AccessinfoDetails> list = new List<AccessinfoDetails>()
        {
            new AccessinfoDetails
            {
                Devices = distinct,
                ixiModem = tixiModem
            }
        };

        return list.AsQueryable();
    }
```